# Incoming call on 2nd iPhone without SIM Card

Tags: iphone, call

Yesterday, i was going to setup my new iPhone 6.
So i did a backup of my iPhone 5, exchanged the SIM card and restored the iPhone 6. The restore did not went well, so i switched put the SIM card back to my iPhone 5.
I left both phones switched on.
Now, whenever i receive a call, both iPhones ring. And i can connect the call on either iphone. How is this possible?

Comment: It is possible because of the new features on iOS 8.

Comment: Indeed it is, just as @JashJacob said, iOS 8/OSX Yosemite Continuity feature makes it possible. For more information see https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/continuity/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS 8 has this new feature called **Continuity**. Which basically means you can make and receive phone calls on your iOS devices as long as your iPhone is on the same Wi-Fi network.


Source: [Apple](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/continuity/)

Go to the phone with the active cellular SIM and you can disable this in settings app:

- Phone
- Calls on Other Devices
- Allow Calls (turn them all off or disable some but not all other devices if you prefer)

Comment: I had the same problem. You have use the new phone to go to Settings, then go to Phone. There is an option to have calls on other devices. You have to turn it off if you no longer want to receive phone calls on your old phone. It will stop the issue.

Comment: You have to turn off the phone call settings on the phone that you don't want to have calls on.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue:

```
Settings > Facetime > iPhone cellular calls > Switch off
```